# How to add dimensions file only for HDPI devices and less(mdpi...)

Tags: android

I want to have separate file with dimensions(dimen.xml) 
only for phone with hdpi and less density.

Unfortunately when I add folder "values-hdpi" with dimen.xml, 
the devices with xhdpi and tablets also use it.

Comment: add empty dimen.xml file to values-xhdp

Comment: it doesn't work with empty dimen.xml, devices with xhdpi still take values from hdpi folder.

I got solution that was suggested by eriuzo (look below), it work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid xhdpi devices to use your hdpi dimens.xml, move your current values/dimen.xml to values-xhdpi folder. This will cause xhdpi devices (and higher) to use that instead.

As for tablets, actually some tablets are of mdpi density. I think you will want to use another qualifier, e.g. screen size to distinguish between tablets and phones

For more info please read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html